# IBM WCM protected content redirected user to /wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login.jsp with hostname and port insted of domain name

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal, lotus-wcm, ibm-wcm

I have a query that is surrounded by a fair bit of grey area. When a user accesses the WCM servlet using the authenticated context (**www.mywebsite.com/wps/wcm/myconnect/xyz/**), if user is not login it is redirect user to **hostname:port/wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login.jsp**

I would like if user is not login user should be redirected to **http://www.mywebsite.com/wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login.jsp** instead of **http://hostname:10039/wps/wcm/webinterface/login/login.jsp**.

So, is it possible to achieve this and if so, would anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure `WCM_HOST` and `WCM_PORT` variables with the fully qualified host name used to access the WCM.

In admin console:

- slect `Environment > WebSphere Variables`
- From the Scope drop-down menu, select the `Node=nodename, Server=servername`
- Update the `WCM_HOST` and `WCM_PORT` variables
- Save, Restart.